# AngularJs: Ng-model object and single model Together

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-options

I do not have enough English to describe it, but I think you will understand it from the codes.
Basically my problem is that ng-model = "" ng-options = "" does not come up with form data when used together.

```
<select class="form-control" name="car_id" ng-model="car_id" ng-options="I.car_brand_code as I.car_brand_name for I in CarList" ng-change="GetState()" >
                                    <option value="">Select Car</option>
                                </select>
```

The selection box for the brands of these cars

```
<div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="mtb10">Model Year</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="modelYear" class="form-control" ng-model="data.modelYear" placeholder="Car Year...">
                                </div>
```

This is the other form objects. Where ng-model is a different data "data." I can get it. How can I get the value in the selection box.

I need to get the "car_id" value.

Comment: In your ng-options you have "I.car_brand_code as I.car_brand_name...". This means whatever you select will have the value I.car_brand_code and set that as the model value you specify in ng-model. I need to see more of the code to provide you with a better answer. If you can provide a plunker I can point you in the exact direction.

Comment: Or if you can supply your controller code I can help more

Comment: Here is a simple example of working with ng-model and ng-options https://embed.plnkr.co/nUz7nABi3Bz4oSGH8FKH/

Comment: Otm.factory ('LocationService', işlev ($ http) {var fac = {}; fac.GetCountry = işlev () {return $ http.get ('http://otm.dev/carBrand')}; fac .GetState = işlev (arac_id) {return $ http.get ('http://otm.dev/carModel?id='+arac_id)}; fac.GetPrice = işlev (model_id) {return $ http.get (' http : //otm.dev/carPrice? ModelId = '+ model_id)}; return fac;});

LocationService.GetCountry().then(function(d) {
       $scope.AracList = d.data;
    }, function (error) {
        alert('Error!');
    });
 `

Comment: @T.Arslan did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

- On change of the dropdown options pass the selected value into the function as a param.
- Use [**array.filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to fetch the `model year` for the selected car based on the car id.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.CarList = [
      {
      "car_brand_code": 1,
      "car_brand_name": "Maruti",
      "model_year": 1990
      },
      {
      "car_brand_code": 2,
      "car_brand_name": "Ford",
      "model_year": 2005
      }
    ];
    
    $scope.GetState = function(carId) {
      var selectedCar = $scope.CarList.filter(function(item) {
        return item.car_brand_code == carId;
      });
      $scope.data = {
        "modelYear" : selectedCar[0].model_year
      }
    };
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select class="form-control" name="car_id" ng-model="car_id" ng-options="I.car_brand_code as I.car_brand_name for I in CarList" ng-change="GetState(car_id)" >
    <option value="">Select Car</option>
  </select>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="mtb10">Model Year</label>
    <input type="text" name="modelYear" class="form-control" ng-model="data.modelYear" placeholder="Car Year...">
  </div>
</div>
```